# To find an example for which $closure(\cup A_\alpha)\ne\cup closure(A_\alpha)$

Tags: general-topology

Give an example where closure of $(\cup A_\alpha)\ne \cup closure (A_\alpha)$ provided $A_\alpha$ are subsets of a topological space.

If I consider $R$ to be a topological space with standard topology and $A_n=(n,n+1)$ where $n\in N$ then will the equality hold?

Comment: You mean $A_n=(n,n+1)\subset\mathbb R$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ and where $\mathbb R$ is equipped with its usual topology? No, then both sides will equal $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

In a topological space where singletons are closed you could take $A_x=\{x\}$ for $x\in U$ where $U$ is an open set that is not closed.

Comment: Can I know in which topological space Singletons are closed( please specify)?

Comment: That are exactly the topological spaces that are [T1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space), but you might not be familiar with that yet. An example is $\mathbb R$ equipped with usual topology.